# Custom Dependent Dropdown in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement two dropdowns in my registration page with custom fields that prompt a user to select their phone brand and the specific model of their phone.

I want to have the phone model dropdown to be dependent of the phone brand dropdown.

In other words, if I select that I have an Apple phone, the phone model dropdown should only give me the options Iphone 6, Iphone 7, Iphone 8, etc.

So far I have not been able to discover how to do a custom dependent form so I tried starting small and doing one regular dropdown. Unfortunately, I was also unable to do that.

To add the regular dropdown I added the following to my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

PHONES = (
    ('samsung','SAMSUNG'),
    ('iphone', 'IPHONE'),
    ('oneplus','ONEPLUS'),
    ('lg','LG'),
)
```

```
class Phones(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=PHONES, default='iphone')
```

And then adding the following to **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from main.models import Phones

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User, Phones
        fields = ("username", "email", "phone", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save() #saves to db
        return user
```

Any help implementing a dependent dropdown with custom fields in my registration form would be greatly appreciated. I have tried looking at tutorials on this topic but have not found anything that is written for beginners and is specifically for custom dependent dropdowns.

Comment: you can not do it in single Django-form. Either implement it something on front-end/ in Django-template. or learn [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html), or this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845918/dynamic-drop-down-list-in-django-forms)